# How to fix import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'; Depricated Fix

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

Does anyone know what is the fix for the decricated import of ionic Plugins?

I'm following a tutorial and I cant proceed until I fix it..

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Storage} = Plugins;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean what is the new way of importing plugins? I assume you mean previously we used to do something similar to:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import { MyImport } = Plugins;
```

If that is the question you're asking, then Capacitor 3 now uses modulated plugins so they're all independent of each other.

You now import them directly, e.g:

```
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage';
```

Available Capacitor plugins are [here](https://capacitorjs.com/).

### Capacitor 4:

Capacitor Storage has now been renamed to Preferences in Capacitor 4.

So your new code would look like this:

```
import { Preferences } from '@capacitor/preferences';
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

That ended up being my solution.

Comment: For "@capacitor/core": "3.5.1" error is something like Cannot find module '@capacitor/storage' or its corresponding type declarations.(Ionic/angular)